# What is the name/number of this brick

Tags: technic, part-identification

I was wondering what the two grey tile like bricks in the image below are? I wish to order some online, so would appreciate knowing their name.

[image: Image of grey bricks]

Comment: Hi Kared and welcome to LEGO Answers :) Is there any chance you could edit your image to include some arrows or similar pointing to the exact elements you're asking about?

Comment: If you need any help in the future, you can check out Brickowl, Bricklink, or Firestartoys!

Answer (score 7):

This is a [3743 - Technic, Gear Rack 1 x 4](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3743) and there are 2 times 2 of these in your picture (2 on the left and 2 on the right).

[image]

I guess your description is a little vague, because if you are talking about the middle part (the shining light gray pieces), they are actually not bricks/tiles, but the axle end of an [NXT motor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=53787) (the right side of the motor in the below picture).

[image]

Comment: Yep, I think the question is referring to the end of the motor.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to be certain due to the angle and quality of the image but I think they are these:
[image: Technic, Liftarm 1 x 3 Thick]

Technic, Liftarm 1 x 3 Thick

Item No: 32523

They are/were produced in many colours including both 'light bluish grey' and light grey'.

More details on [bricklink](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=32523&name=Technic,%20Liftarm%201%20x%203%20Thick&category=%5BTechnic,%20Liftarm%5D#T=C)

**Edit**

Just realised you you referred to them as 'tile like bricks' so maybe it is this:

[image: Part 3743 Technic, Gear Rack 1 x 4]

Part 3743 Technic, Gear Rack 1 x 4
[Bricklink link](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3743&name=Technic,%20Gear%20Rack%201%20x%204&category=%5BTechnic,%20Gear%5D#T=C)

It would be a lot easier if you could isolate the elements you are interested in and take better photo